# C# - Some Keys does not function

Tags: c#, visual-studio

According to: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/737799/IntelliSense-TextBox-in-Csharp

Why does the "Enter " key work while the "Period" key doesn't work?

```
//text box key press event

txtControl.KeyPress += (s, kpeArgs) =>
{
    if ((kpeArgs.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) || (kpeArgs.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemPeriod))
   {
      if (lstControl.Visible == true)
     {
        lstControl.Focus();
     }
      kpeArgs.Handled = true;

   }
}
```

---

```
//listbox keyup event

lstControl.KeyUp += (s, kueArgs) =>
{
   if ((kueArgs.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (kueArgs.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod))
  {
    string StrLS = GetLastString(txtControl.Text);
    int LIOLS = txtControl.Text.LastIndexOf(StrLS);
    string TempStr = txtControl.Text.Remove(LIOLS);
    txtControl.Text = TempStr + ((ListBox)s).SelectedItem.ToString();
    txtControl.Select(txtControl.Text.Length, 0);
    txtControl.Focus();
    lstControl.Hide();
  }
}
```

I am a beginner that learns for fun. So try not to give an answer that is too complicated or too detailed, OK? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
kpeArgs.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemPeriod)
```

to this:

```
kpeArgs.KeyChar == '.'
```

Keys.OemPeriod is not '.', but '3/4' or 0xBE or 190. I dont see it in US keyboard.